# Invoke NERDCommenter in insert mode?

Tags: vim, macvim

In my `.vimrc`, I have the following mapping which I use to toggle comments using the excellent [NERDCommenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter) plugin:

```
vmap <D-/> ,c<space>gv
map <D-/> ,c<space>
```

Works great for this TextMate refugee.

However, I'd like it to work in Insert mode as well. Roughly:

- Use the same combo (command-/)
- Switch to normal mode
- Execute the toggle
- Bonus points for saving the cursor position, I suppose.

My `.vimrc` skills don't extend to this. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `imap` to map commands in insert mode. I think the following should work.

```
imap <D-/> <esc>,c<space>
```

Comment: Duh, I guess I should have been able to figure that out myself. Thanks!